# Listview.Refresh() in VB.NET is slow

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, listview, refresh

I am having an issue with rendering ListView icons. For example I have 16 items only. They all use icons of size 32x32. It takes two seconds to display the icons, and the icons appears from buttom to top.

This is what i did:
1- add 16 items to list view
2- the listview is bound to an image list with icons 16x16
3- ListView is RTL, with groups
3- added a button that runs the following: FoldersListView.Refresh()

the rendering after pressing that button takes 2 seconds.

Any advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Hi there. I noticed that when the control is RTL, the refresh is very slow. Switching the direction to LTR makes the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

What are you computer specs? try running the app without the debugger outside VS. but first close VS, see if the problem is still present, apps usually run faster without the debugger

Comment: Hi there. It seems the issue is related to the direction of the control. As soon as I switch the direction from RTL to LTR, the refresh returns to normal.